# jquery hover function with CSS transition effect ONLY working on second hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Very odd. The below code ONLY works on **second** hover. For instance the page is loaded, toggle works, but transition animation **does not work until second hover** each time, consistently.

**jQuery**:

```
$('.greenBox').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
    $(this).removeClass('contracted');
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('expanded');
    $(this).addClass('contracted');
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.greenBox {
    background-image: url("../images/background_bubble.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    // transition:max-height .5s linear;
    // background: linear-gradient(#69af38, #8fba35);
    transition: .8s; 
    color: #FFF; 
    width: 310px; 
    height: 137px;
    position: relative; 
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    // -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, height 0.5s ease, bottom 0.5s ease;
    // -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, height 0.5s ease, bottom 0.5s ease;
    // -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, height 0.5s ease, bottom 0.5s ease;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
    // transition: background-color 0.5s ease, height 0.5s ease, bottom 0.5s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 7px;
    // -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 75%, 60% 75%, 49% 86%, 37% 75%, 0% 75%); 
    // clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 75%, 60% 75%, 49% 86%, 37% 75%, 0% 75%);
    .noLink {
        color: #FFF;
        &:hover {
            cursor: auto;
            color: #FFF;
            background: linear-gradient(#69af38, #8fba35);
        }
    }
}
```

**and.**

```
.contracted {
    // transition: 11s;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**and.**

```
.expanded { 
    height: auto;
    min-height:150px;
    max-height:750px; 
    // transition: 11s;
    // margin-top:5px;
    // to make the box move up add back the bottom 300px
    // bottom: 300px;
    background: linear-gradient(#812990, #9e248e);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear; 
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#812990, #9E248E);
}
```

Comment: Make sure the initial element has the class `contracted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the element starts with the class `contracted`. Before I added that it only worked on second hover for me as well.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/czrqkorn/

```
<div class="greenBox contracted"></div>
```

Comment: Simplified syntax for the OP's benefit: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/czrqkorn/1/

Comment: gracias!! Simplified is always better!

Comment: Of course, you don't even need scripting for this. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/czrqkorn/2/